# How do I access a control from a different page within my site?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview

Or maybe I don't need to, I don't know. Here's what I'm trying to do. I have a gridview on one page and when I click on an item, it takes the ID and links it to another page that displays all the info that goes with the item in the gridview. On the second page, I want to be able to insert a photo with some text into my database, but I want to make sure it inserts with the proper blogID (that was clicked on from the first page). Here's my code so far:

EditBlogPosts.aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" 
    AutoGenerateEditButton="True" 
    DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID"
    AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="Gray"  
    AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="editGridFormat" RowStyle-CssClass="editGridFormat"        
    RowStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" 
    onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

Code behind:

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
    Response.Redirect("~/EditThisPost.aspx?ID=" + row.Cells[2].Text);
}
```

EditThisPost.aspx

```
<asp:FormView ID="Formview1" runat="server" DefaultMode="Insert" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" >
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="TextforPhotoLabel" runat="server" Text="Put your text to go with your photo here:" /><br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="PhotoText" runat="server" Rows="10" Columns="100" /><br /><br />
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
        <asp:Label ID="UploadStatusLabel" runat="server" Text="Status: " /><br />
        <asp:Button ID="UploadButton" runat="server" OnClick="UploadFile" Text="Insert Item" /><br />
    </InsertItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

Code behind (paying special attention to the line where I declare int blogID):

```
protected void UploadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txtPhotoText = (TextBox)Formview1.FindControl("PhotoText");
    FileUpload FileUpload1 = (FileUpload)Formview1.FindControl("FileUpload1");
    Label UploadStatusLabel = (Label)Formview1.FindControl("UploadStatusLabel");
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {
            if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType == "image/jpeg")
            {
                if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength < 10240000)
                {
                    string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
                    FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/photos/PeoplePhotos/") + filename);
                    UploadStatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: Complete!";
                    string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\TravelJoansDB.mdb;";
                    string cmdstr = "INSERT INTO BlogEntryItems (BlogID, Picture, PicText1) VALUES (?,?,?)";
                    int blogID = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["ID"]);

                    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
                    OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(cmdstr, con);

                    con.Open();
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BlogID", blogID);
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Picture", filename);
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PicText1", txtPhotoText);
                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
                else
                    UploadStatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file has to be less than 10 MB!";
            }
            else
                UploadStatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: Only JPEG files are accepted!";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            UploadStatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

I truly appreciate any help. I was thinking I could somehow get the ID that was passed to make the "~\EditThisPost.aspx?ID=" a valid link. But if there is a better way to do it or if the way I'm thinking doesn't even exist, then how can I accomplish what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get the blogID  as below

```
int blogID  = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["ID"]);
```

I would use `int.TryParse` to avoid exceptions in case of non integer values in the query string

```
int blogID;
int.TryParse(Request.Querystring["ID"], out blogID);
```

Comment: Hey, I'm pretty sure you're right. I just want to ask now I'm getting a different error that has to do with inserting into the database. When I press the button, it gives me an error saying "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors" Any ideas? Also, look at my updated code please, I added some stuff.

Answer (score 1):

add a Viewstate-backed property to EditThisPost.aspx to hold BlogID: -

http://www.codingwith.net/2008/01/viewstate-backed-properties-part-one.html

Set this property in PageLoad of EditThisPost.aspx, and then use it in UploadFile.

Comment: I'm voting your answer up because it is something I've never heard about and will be looking into, but the other guy's answer worked like a charm and very simple!

Comment: Viewstate-backed properties are a fairly common technique. Thanks for the upvote and good luck ;)